# Is it possible to compress a DMG format file in the form of an executable?

Tags: dmg-image

I had some confusion and so I got a `.dmg` format file and I researched about it as it is a **mac** file so I unpacked it using **7zip**, which contains a set of files and different folders.

How can I make the specific files use the windows installation paths or something like that to compress to an executable?

Maybe **compress** sounds like a wrong term but there should exist some kind of compilation to apply on these files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, what is your goal here? What problem are you trying to solve by trying to run Mac files on Windows? Why do you think turning tha into an executable will achieve anything?

Comment: Due to some confusion I got the file for **mac** so before trying to download the program again I would like to know if there is a way to convert it to a **Windows** executable.

Comment: On the web I get different resources indicating that I could use **7zip** or some other program to mount images of this type, but I find that they are made up of folders and some in specific that have the name of the program like this **Program.app** also contains sub directories with **.mac** format files so I thought I could compile them as a **`C#`** type program but I think it is more complicated, otherwise I would just have to download the file again correct format file as long as there are no long-term complications in SE network.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what you try to do with it, you won't persuade it to run on Windows.

It's already compiled - for Mac. The fact that you can actually see all the resource components is because windows doesn't even know what the .app format is, so instead it treats is as a folder.

Your best bet now is to just throw it all in the trash & get the Windows version instead.